# How to animate Texture change in Blender Internal

Tags: texturing, uv

I want to change the texture of specific objects, making shift across the surface of the object. I don't know how to insert keyframes for UV mapping though.
How can I make the image on the object move? 
Think of a magical cape, with the design constantly flowing on the cloth.
How could I achieve something like that?

Comment: Does this help: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32091/can-i-have-a-unique-uv-map-for-each-frame, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh ?

Comment: Related, or maybe even a duplicate? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32091/can-i-have-a-unique-uv-map-for-each-frame

Comment: I dunno. It looks like it might work. They seem to be about changing the whole UV texture to another. I want to slide the texture across the surface of the material.

Comment: How about this? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35887/how-to-create-and-apply-a-moving-texture

Comment: "page not found" "Page was voluntarily removed by its author"
@Gonzou found another one that says I'm  "Mildly doomed"

Comment: @Gonzou not everybody can read deleted questions and answers, only users with more than 2000 rep.

Comment: @BookWyrm17 See another related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes

Comment: @BookWyrm17 The answer below shows how to animate textures in Blender Internal as you asked. Tell me if this is the effect you want to achieve. I'll try to update an answer soon to show you how to do it in a different way (using AnimAll addon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may move the overlayed texture pattern over the other texture animating its ***Offset*** parameters.
[image]

Prepare the image with your pattern (use a .png image).
[image]

Set up the textures as pictured below. Check the *Color* box in *Influence* panel.
[image]

In *Mapping* panel animate the desired parameters. 
[image]

To loop the animation indefinitely you can use a ***Cycles Modifier***. Go to the *Graph Editor*, press <kbd>N</kbd> to open its *properties shelf* and add this modifier in *Modifiers* panel.
[image]

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You may shift textures animating the ***Offset*** value of the gradient texture, which works as a mask for transition between two textures.
[image]

Prepare two different textures.
[image]

Add a new material to your surface and unwrap it. Give it two image textures (set their *type* to ***Image or Movie*** and *mapping coordinates* to ***UV***). Now add one more texture. Set its *type* to ***Blend*** and place it between previously added ones. In *Influence* panel uncheck the *Color* box and check *Alpha*. Check the ***RGB to Intensity*** and ***Stencil*** boxes. 
[image]

Now the gradient texture acts like a mask. In *Colors* panel check the ***Ramp*** box and use sliders to define the smoothness/sharpness of the transition between textures.
[image]

In *Mapping* panel change the *Offset* value of the *X* window so you can see only one texture. Hovering your cursor over that window press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe. Go to another frame, change the *Offset* value and press <kbd>I</kbd> again.
[image]

Comment: This would be great for one of the problems I have. But the issue I have now is that I don't know how to make the texture move across the surface of the material.
How can I make the image on the object move? 
Think of a magical cape, with the design constantly flowing on the cloth.
How could I achieve something like that?

Comment: If I got your idea correctly, you want to move the texture pattern from the top of the cape to the bottom of it and repeat it continously, right?

Comment: Correct. While the material stays the same shape, I want the pattern to move.

Comment: Ok, done. It's actually much simplier to create. Please see my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

this maybe is a bit dumb but easy: you could add an object moving along 1 or more axis, in the environment but out of sight, add a driver node linked to the object location. add keyframes to differnet object locations based on the values you want to obtain (for example if I want my tecture parameter to assume values 1 or 2 I will shift the object position from Z = 1 to Z = 2 at the desired frame). Do the same for the other axes, Y and X. now you have potentially 3 values that are changing every frame of the amount you want and that can affect your texture in 3 different ways.